# TRANE XE70 GAS FURNACE - HSI only works once

Tags: hvac

My TRANE XE70 Gas Heater HSI (hot surface igniter) will glow hot once and heater works fine, but then doesn't work anymore on the Thermostat cycle.
I've replaced Flame Sensor and HSI Module.
My White-Rodgers Control Panel flashes Yellow light on boot up, then goes to constant Green light and stays solid green.
I have already purchased and I am going to replace the Control Panel but wonder before I do that if there is something else to check for this intermittent HSI issue ?

1. Filter is New
2. Gas Valve is opening on commands from Thermostat
3. Blower is functioning correctly

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this issue by replacing the Control Board and using a longer timing program insert key from 4 seconds to 7.

Answer (score 1):

The furnace is seeing some kind of rather serious error and going into a lockout mode. The control board will give you an error code that is supposed to assist in trouble-shooting the problem.  This code is typically delivered through a series of flashing lights.  Unless you have unlimited money to throw at this furnace in parts you may want to consider professional assistance. Good Luck.